# Как десериализовать объекты в объекте Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

Получаю Json такого вида. Много объектов в одном объекте. Пытаюсь написать кастомный GsonDeserializer для использования в Retrofit.

Поля у всех объектов одинаковы и постояны.
Проблема в том что имена  объектов заранее не известны и объекты не в массиве, а в объекте. Поэтому я не могу ни пробежаться по ним, ни получить каждый по имени.

Имя объекта должно содержаться в поле POJO-класса. А во всех гайдах который я находил, имя POJO-класса - это имя объекта. Но я этого имени заранее не знаю.

```
{
  "Object1": {
    "fild_1": "text",
    "fild_2": "text",
    "fild_3": "text"
  },
"Object2": {
    "fild_1": "text",
    "fild_2": "text",
    "fild_3": "text"
  },
.
.
.
}

public class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer {
    @Override
    public List<MyModel> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {

        ArrayList<MyModel> list = new ArrayList<>;
\\создали список объектов models - pojo-класс, для объектов вложеных в корневой объект

        JsonObject modelsJsonObj = json.getAsJsonObject();
\\получили корнейвой объект с объектами models
\\как из него дальше вытащить объекты, имена которых я не знаю??

    }
}
```

Comment: Прведите пример кода - "Пытаюсь написать кастомный GsonDeserializer"

Comment: @RomanC Я же написал, что не могу достать объекты т.к. не знаю их имени. Нечего приводить. Вот этот класс. Но не знаю какой толк мне его показывать.Upd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись без кастомных десериализаторов - просто спарсить в `Map<String, MyModel>`. Gson спарсит имена объектов в ключи, а сами объекты в значения.

```
Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, MyModel>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson(json, mapType);

gson.toJson(foo, mapType);
```

Имена и количество объектов роли не играют - главное чтобы сами объекты соответствовали одной модели.

Comment: Спасибо! А то я уже хотел как стрингу разбирать, посимвольно)